# Concatenate several columns to comma separated strings by group

Tags: r

Background: I am in the process of annotating SNPs from a GWAS in an organism without much annotation. I am using the chained tBLASTn table from UCSC along with biomaRt to map each SNP to a probable gene(s).

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            SNP   hu_mRNA     gene
 chr1.111642529 NM_002107    H3F3A
 chr1.111642529 NM_005324    H3F3B
 chr1.111801684 BC098118     <NA>
 chr1.111925084 NM_020435    GJC2
  chr1.11801605 AK027740     <NA>
  chr1.11801605 NM_032849    C13orf33
 chr1.151220354 NM_018913    PCDHGA10
 chr1.151220354 NM_018918    PCDHGA5
```

What I would like to end up with is a single row for each SNP, and comma delimit the genes and hu_mRNAs. Here is what I am after:

```
            SNP            hu_mRNA    gene
 chr1.111642529 NM_002107,NM_005324   H3F3A
 chr1.111801684  BC098118,NM_020435   GJC2
  chr1.11801605  AK027740,NM_032849   C13orf33
 chr1.151220354 NM_018913,NM_018918   PCDHGA10,PCDHGA5
```

Now I know I can do this with a flick of the wrist in perl, but I really want to do this all in R. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` with `paste` for each one and `merge` at the end:

```
x <- structure(list(SNP = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L), .Label = c("chr1.111642529", "chr1.111801684", "chr1.111925084", 
"chr1.11801605", "chr1.151220354"), class = "factor"), hu_mRNA = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("AK027740", "BC098118", 
"NM_002107", "NM_005324", "NM_018913", "NM_018918", "NM_020435", 
"NM_032849"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("<NA>", "C13orf33", "GJC2", "H3F3A", 
"H3F3B", "PCDHGA10", "PCDHGA5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SNP", 
"hu_mRNA", "gene"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))

a1 <- aggregate(hu_mRNA~SNP,data=x,paste,sep=",")
a2 <- aggregate(gene~SNP,data=x,paste,sep=",")
merge(a1,a2)
             SNP              hu_mRNA              gene
1 chr1.111642529 NM_002107, NM_005324      H3F3A, H3F3B
2 chr1.111801684             BC098118              <NA>
3 chr1.111925084            NM_020435              GJC2
4  chr1.11801605  AK027740, NM_032849    <NA>, C13orf33
5 chr1.151220354 NM_018913, NM_018918 PCDHGA10, PCDHGA5
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks! I did not know the `aggregate` function. I modified slightly to remove the spaces after the commas, eg: `a1 <- aggregate(hu_mRNA~SNP,data=x,paste,collapse=",")
a2 <- aggregate(gene~SNP,data=x,paste,collapse=",")`

Comment: @caddymob Good call, it seems that `sep` actually has no effect in this case, only `collapse` does.

Comment: @James. Gabor's solution suggested that a one-liner with `collapse=","`  would work.

Answer (score 12):

You could do this in one line using `plyr`, as it is a classic `split-apply-combine` problem. You split using `SNP`, apply `paste` with `collapse` and assemble the pieces back into a data frame.

```
plyr::ddply(x, .(SNP), colwise(paste), collapse = ",")
```

If you want to do `data` reshaping in R at the `flick of a wrist`, learn `plyr` and `reshape2` :). Another flick of the wrist solution using `data.table`, really useful if you are dealing with massive amounts of data.

```
data.table::data.table(x)[,lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","),'SNP']
```

Answer (score 5):

First set up the test data.  Note that we have made the columns to be of `"character"` class rather than `"factor"` by using `as.is=TRUE` :

```
Lines <- "SNP   hu_mRNA     gene
 chr1.111642529 NM_002107    H3F3A
 chr1.111642529 NM_005324    H3F3B
 chr1.111801684 BC098118     <NA>
 chr1.111925084 NM_020435    GJC2
  chr1.11801605 AK027740     <NA>
  chr1.11801605 NM_032849    C13orf33
 chr1.151220354 NM_018913    PCDHGA10
 chr1.151220354 NM_018918    PCDHGA5"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "data.txt")
DF <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, na.strings = "<NA>", as.is = TRUE)
```

Now try this `aggregate` statement:

```
> aggregate(. ~ SNP, DF, toString)
             SNP              hu_mRNA              gene
1 chr1.111642529 NM_002107, NM_005324      H3F3A, H3F3B
2 chr1.111925084            NM_020435              GJC2
3  chr1.11801605            NM_032849          C13orf33
4 chr1.151220354 NM_018913, NM_018918 PCDHGA10, PCDHGA5
```

Comment: And by the same principle, this should succeed: `aggregate(. ~ SNP, DF, paste, collapse=",")`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved using `reshape2`'s `melt` and `dcast` operations. With this approach, `melt` transforms the data to "long" format first, and then the values are `dcast`-ed with the same operation, `paste(..., collapse = ",")`:

```
library(reshape2)

x <- read.table(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  header = TRUE,
  na.strings = "<NA>",
  text = "            SNP   hu_mRNA     gene
 chr1.111642529 NM_002107    H3F3A
 chr1.111642529 NM_005324    H3F3B
 chr1.111801684 BC098118     <NA>
 chr1.111925084 NM_020435    GJC2
  chr1.11801605 AK027740     <NA>
  chr1.11801605 NM_032849    C13orf33
 chr1.151220354 NM_018913    PCDHGA10
 chr1.151220354 NM_018918    PCDHGA5")

(xm <-melt(x, id.vars = "SNP", na.rm = TRUE))
##               SNP variable     value
## 1  chr1.111642529  hu_mRNA NM_002107
## 2  chr1.111642529  hu_mRNA NM_005324
## 3  chr1.111801684  hu_mRNA  BC098118
## 4  chr1.111925084  hu_mRNA NM_020435
## 5   chr1.11801605  hu_mRNA  AK027740
## 6   chr1.11801605  hu_mRNA NM_032849
## 7  chr1.151220354  hu_mRNA NM_018913
## 8  chr1.151220354  hu_mRNA NM_018918
## 9  chr1.111642529     gene     H3F3A
## 10 chr1.111642529     gene     H3F3B
## 12 chr1.111925084     gene      GJC2
## 14  chr1.11801605     gene  C13orf33
## 15 chr1.151220354     gene  PCDHGA10
## 16 chr1.151220354     gene   PCDHGA5

(xc <- dcast(xm, SNP~variable, fun.aggregate = paste, collapse = ","))
##              SNP             hu_mRNA             gene
## 1 chr1.111642529 NM_002107,NM_005324      H3F3A,H3F3B
## 2 chr1.111801684            BC098118                 
## 3 chr1.111925084           NM_020435             GJC2
## 4  chr1.11801605  AK027740,NM_032849         C13orf33
## 5 chr1.151220354 NM_018913,NM_018918 PCDHGA10,PCDHGA5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, which IHMO is the most readable:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(SNP) %>%
  summarize(
    genes = paste(gene, collapse = ','),
    hu_mRNA = paste(hu_mRNA, collapse = ',')
  )
```

The result:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

             SNP            genes             hu_mRNA
          (fctr)            (chr)               (chr)
1 chr1.111642529      H3F3A,H3F3B NM_002107,NM_005324
2 chr1.111801684             <NA>            BC098118
3 chr1.111925084             GJC2           NM_020435
4  chr1.11801605    <NA>,C13orf33  AK027740,NM_032849
5 chr1.151220354 PCDHGA10,PCDHGA5 NM_018913,NM_018918
```