# How to create a table with two-factorial data

Tags: r, r-table

is there a possibility to show data that is two-factorial in a table using R?

Please consider my example with replicates.

So one has two or more values in every cell.

I tried using ftable() and table() but am not getting anywhere :(

Thank you so much for helping

Example input

```
A    B    Value
1    1    1.2
1    1    1.4
1    2    2.1
1    2    2.0
2    1    1.1
2    1    1.2
2    2    3.1
2    2    3.1
```

Desired output, something like
[image]

Comment: My primary intention is to illustrate the data, because I want to show it in a R Markdown Presentation. So I am looking for the R representation as "matrix" with two rows and two columns, where each cell holds two values, as in my example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique rows with multiple comma separated entries in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083984/unique-rows-with-multiple-comma-separated-entries-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for your patience so far. You see, my problem (when described the right way) is pretty basic.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thank you very much. Is there a chance to name the columns and rows? There is just the simple 'A' in the upper left corner in my output und it is not clear, which values are B and A. But your solution is pretty nice :) And do you know the newline-character? collapse= '\n' does not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would be helpful:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dcast.data.table(
  as.data.table(df)[, `:=`(A = paste0("A", A),   ## Prefix A values with "A"
                           B = paste0("B", B))], ## Prefix B values with "B"
  A ~ B, value.var = "Value",                    ## Our casting formula
  fun.aggregate = function(x)                    ## Our aggregation formula
    paste(sprintf("%2.2f", x), collapse = "/"))  ## sprintf -> uniform format
#     A        B1        B2
# 1: A1 1.20/1.40 2.10/2.00
# 2: A2 1.10/1.20 3.10/3.10
```

I've added comments in the code to explain what's going on at each step.

Comment: First you need df<-read.table("mydata.txt"). Is it possible to paste with newlines? Very nice solution btw

Comment: @feinmann, I don't think that you would be able to get new lines in the console this way. "\n" would need another escape, if you wanted to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The `tapply` function is the standard base-R mechanism for getting afunction to be applied to a cross-classified value:

```
tapply(dat$Value, list(A=dat$A,B=dat$B) , function(x) paste(x,collapse="/"))
#----------
   B
A   1         2        
  1 "1.2/1.4" "2.1/2"  
  2 "1.1/1.2" "3.1/3.1"
```

If you wanted annotation:

```
tapply(dat$Value, list(A=dat$A,B=dat$B) , function(x) paste("V1=",x[1],"V2=",x[2]))
#--------------
   B
A   1                 2                
  1 "V1= 1.2 V2= 1.4" "V1= 2.1 V2= 2"  
  2 "V1= 1.1 V2= 1.2" "V1= 3.1 V2= 3.1"
```